# Map just one field with Automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm using Automapper to define a mapping configuration between some objects. I need to retrieve single mapped values for the destination based on the configuration.

Let's say I have a domain object

```
class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

and a corresponding DTO

```
class PersonDTO
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

and a mapping

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Person, PersonDTO>()
    .ForMember(
        dest => dest.FullName, 
        opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.FirstName + " " + src.LastName));
```

I'd like a method like `Mapper.MapField<PersonDTO>(person, x => x.FullName)` that returns just one mapped value (that would get assigned to the specified field in a full mapping). Is there any way I can do this without mapping the whole object and extracting the value from the result?

Comment: why dont you simply assign the field? as it is only one field.

Comment: This is just an example, my actual objects are more complicated and I need a general way of using the mapping configuration to obtain a value from a source object. I don't need the destination object, just the field value.

Answer (score 0):

First create a [resolver](https://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Value%20Resolvers) and then use the resolve using method in your mapper call.

```
public class PersonNameResolver : ValueResolver<Person, PersonDTO>
{
    protected override PersonDTO ResolveCore(Person source)
    {
        return new PersonDTO
        {
            FirstName = source.FirstName,
            LastName = source.LastName
        };
    }
}
```

Once this is created, use the following in your mapper call.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Person, PersonDTO>()
    .ForMember(
        dest => dest.Name, 
        opts => opts.ResolveUsing<PersonNameResolver>().FromMember(o => o))
```

Comment: This should only map the items defined between the two. Can you clarify just a bit more? If you add other fields to PersonDTO they should not get mapped using the PersonNameResolver.